# XPath / XSLT OR XQuery for grouping data

Tags: xpath, xslt, xquery

I have an input xml, as mentioned below.

```
    <root>
    <Response_Data>
        <Worker>
            <Worker_Data>
                <Worker_ID>100</Worker_ID>
                <User_ID>test</User_ID>
                <Personal_DAta>
                    <Name_Data>
                        <Legal_Name_Data>
                            <Name_Detail_Data>
                                <Country_Reference>
                                    <ID>AU</ID>
                                </Country_Reference>
                            </Name_Detail_Data>
                        </Legal_Name_Data>
                    </Name_Data>
                </Personal_DAta>
                <Employment_Data>
                    <Worker_Job_Data>
                        <Position_Data>
                            <Position_Reference>
                                <ID>P100</ID>
                            </Position_Reference>
                        </Position_Data>
                    </Worker_Job_Data>
                </Employment_Data>
            </Worker_Data>
        </Worker>
    <Worker>
            <Worker_Data>
                <Worker_ID>102</Worker_ID>
                <User_ID>test</User_ID>
                <Personal_DAta>
                    <Name_Data>
                        <Legal_Name_Data>
                            <Name_Detail_Data>
                                <Country_Reference>
                                    <ID>US</ID>
                                </Country_Reference>
                            </Name_Detail_Data>
                        </Legal_Name_Data>
                    </Name_Data>
                </Personal_DAta>
                <Employment_Data>
                    <Worker_Job_Data>
                        <Position_Data>
                            <Position_Reference>
                                <ID>P102</ID>
                            </Position_Reference>
                        </Position_Data>
                    </Worker_Job_Data>
                </Employment_Data>
            </Worker_Data>
        </Worker>
    </Response_Data>
</root>
```

Requirement - For each worker, I need the data grouped by country, as mentioned below

Country - number of workers
Worker_ID, Position_Reference-ID

So for above example, the output should be

IN - 1
100, P100

AU - 2
101, P101
102, P102

AND so on..
My system supports XPATH 3.0 / XSLT 3.0.

I have tried below XSLT code for this output

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="5"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/Get_Workers_Response/Response_Data" group-by="./Worker/Worker_Data/Personal_Data/Name_Data/Legal_Name_Data/Name_Detail_Data/Country_Reference/ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="./Worker/Worker_Data/Worker_ID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output I am getting is

100 101 102IN
100 101 102AU

I have not inserted position reference in the code yet, as I have been trying to get the worker id output first.

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you. -- Note that  [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) is probably the most often asked XSLT question here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I have updated the xslt code I have tried along with the xml.

Comment: I found the solution with some more efforts. Copying the code here for info. Basically, I needed to run another loop inside for-each-group to capture the values for each group. So each group needs to be processed with another for loop if we wish to have all values within that group. Thanks for your help @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0):

While doing some more research on my question, I realized that
'for-each-group' creates the grouping however, if we wish to access all the records in each group, we need to have another for loop inside the group to track all the values in that group. Here is the code which provides desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="5"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/Get_Workers_Response/Response_Data/Worker" group-by="./Worker_Data/Personal_Data/Name_Data/Legal_Name_Data/Name_Detail_Data/Country_Reference/ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Worker_Data/Worker_ID"/> <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./Worker_Data/Employment_Data/Worker_Job_Data/Position_Data/Position_Reference/ID"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>  
            </xsl:for-each>
            
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
IN
100 P100
AU
101 P101
102 P102
```

Comment: Good to see that you explored and learned to use the `for-each-group group-by` of XSLT 2/3. But as your own input data in the question has a root element named `root` but the posted XSLT in this answer uses an absolute path starting with `/Get_Workers_Response` it doesn't seem like the fitting XSLT sample to your input sample. As for the inner `for-each`, you might be able to write more compact code in XSLT 2 and 3 if you learn about `xsl:value-of separator`.